# Creating Entity Framework Objects from Stored Procedures

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

When using Entity Framework 4, how do you create a **single entity** from a stored procedure?

Comment: I added my answer, but may have misunderstood.  Do you want to retrieve an entity from the database using a stored procedure, or create a new entity and save it to the database using a stored procedure?

Comment: Yeah the main thing is that I don't want the entities having access to the table outside of procedures.

Comment: typically, I'd create a view over every relevant table (which e.g. shows only the "valid" or "non-deleted" entries), and use stored procs for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE (only logical - only mark for deletion) operations on those entities. Well supported in EF4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you add the stored procedure to the model, from the Model Browser right-click the stored procedure under the Store node and select 'Add Function Import'.  In that dialog, indicate what entity should be created:

[image]

You can then use that stored procedure like this:

```
Artist a = ctx.SelectArtist(id).SingleOrDefault();
```

*Edit*

Based on the comments, it sounds like you want to use stored procedures to perform inserts, updates, and deletes.  If you right-click on the entity in the model browser and select 'Stored Procedure Mapping', you'll get a window that lets you specify which stored procedures to use.  MSDN has a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716711.aspx) on how to do this.

HTH